# How to filter object data?

Tags: scala, scala-java-interop

I have list of users of type :

```
java.util.List[User]
```

User is of type :

```
case class User(id: String, type : BigInt)
```

I want to filter into a List of Strings where each String is the id of the user : java.util.List[String]

I could just iterate over each value in the List and just select the id and populate the new List.

Can I use Scala's filter functionality to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to convert to a Scala collection and then back to a Java collection:

```
import collection.JavaConverters._

val l: java.util.List[User] = ...
val l2 = l.asScala.map(_.id).asJava
// l2: java.util.List[java.lang.String] = ...
```

Alternatively, you may be able to write your own collection builders and `CanBuildFrom` implicits for the Java collections, but this would clearly be more work.